# Post custom actions to timeline with publish_stream permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying the following to post custom action on to my timeline. The same effect has been achieved with the Graph API Explorer.

```
    $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId' => '123456789',
                                    'secret' => '123456789',
                                    'cookie' => true));
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

    if($access_token != "") 
    {
        $user = $facebook->getUser();

        if($user != 0)
        {
            $queries = array(array("method" => "POST", "relative_url" => "/me/namespace:action?object=http://www.mysite.com/url/parameters"));

            try 
            {
                $postResponseA = $facebook->api("?batch=".json_encode($queries), "POST");
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) 
            {
                echo 'AF error: '.$e;
            }
        }
    }
```

No errors are thrown. Nothing is ever posted though.

print_r($postResponseA) shows the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [code] => 400 [headers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin [value] => * ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Cache-Control [value] => no-store ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Connection [value] => close ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Content-Type [value] => text/javascript; charset=UTF-8 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Expires [value] => Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT ) [5] => Array ( [name] => Pragma [value] => no-cache ) [6] => Array ( [name] => WWW-Authenticate [value] => OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user." ) ) [body] => {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}} ) )
```

Comment: What are you getting in `$postResponseA` ?

Comment: I updated the question and showed what the variable is equal to.

Comment: Strange. I have an access token. Idk why it's throwing me that error.

Comment: Are you having any user logged in your application ? cause it is giving error `An active access token must be used to query information about the current user`. Also [check](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) the access token you are having to check if it is user access token with permissions or an app access token.

Comment: That's just the thing. I've found that I need the user token instead of the access token. How do I get it?

Comment: Oh common, please … you should have read about that in the docs _before_ you even started with custom actions. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

Comment: I thought the user token was the default

Comment: CBroe, i can assure you Lance has read and reread the docs, it was just a case of getting confused using and passing access tokens.  "User in learning mode."  This issue has been resolved outside of stackoverflow and this QandA can be closed.  
"sensing alot of harshness here."